# sqlquery to get missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table student with following columns

StudentId   SemesterId   ExamYearId 
1                     1                     1 
1                     2                     2 
1                     3                     3 
3                     1                     1 
 
3                     2                     2 
3                     3                     4 
7                     1                     1 
7                     3                     4 
8                     1                     1 
8                     2                     2

I want a query to get all such student for whom no data exists for `semesterid=3` and `examyearid=3`, however same student should have data for `semesterid=2`.

In this case it should return me `studentid=8` as `studentid=8` has data for `semesterid=2` and `examyearid=2` however no data for `examyearid=3` and `semesterid=3`.

Basically I want to be able to input `semesterid` and `examyearid` and find which `studentid`s have not filled data for that `semesterid` and `examyearid`.

Comment: You will get best results here if you attempt to write the query and post what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @SemesterId INT
       ,@ExamYearId INT

SET @SemesterId = 3;
SET @ExamYearId = 3;

SELECT * 
FROM TableName t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM TableName 
              WHERE SemesterId  = @SemesterId - 1
               AND  ExamYearId  = @ExamYearId - 1
               AND  t.StudentId = StudentId   )
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM TableName 
              WHERE SemesterId  = @SemesterId 
               AND  ExamYearId  = @ExamYearId 
               AND  t.StudentId = StudentId   )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT st1.*
  FROM Student st1 
  left join Student st2 
    on st1.id = st2.id 
   and st1.Semesterid=2 
   and st2.Semesterid=3 
   and st2.Examyearid=3 
 where st2.id is null
```